# How to set WebSocket Origin Header from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, websocket, cross-domain

I'm trying to use javascript to make a websocket request from a local `test.dev` page to a server running at ip `123.123.123.123` on behalf of `test.com`. The request goes through, but the `123.123.123.123` server sees the `Origin: test.dev` header in the websocket request and rejects the connection because it wants to see `Origin: test.com`.

Here is the javascript code for connecting the socket:

`ws = new WebSocket("123.123.123.123");`

How can I use javascript to start a websocket connection with a dishonest `Origin` header of `Origin: test.com`?

I was hoping something like this would work, but I can't find any such:

`ws = new WebSocket("123.123.123.123", "test.com");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple solution would be to simply create an entry in your `hosts` file to map `test.com` to `123.123.123.123`. You would need to remove this entry later when you want to connect the "real" `test.com`.

A less hacky solution would require the use of a proxy which can re-write your headers for you on-the-fly. Consider install `nginx` on your system, and then proxing the request to `123.123.123.123` keeping everything the same *except* for the Origin header. Here's the entry you would need in your nginx config file:

```
server {
    server_name test.dev;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://123.123.123.123;
        proxy_set_header Origin test.com;

        # the following 3 are required to proxy WebSocket connections.
        # See more here: http://nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Using `nginx` is another good option, if a little more complex to set up than using a dedicated web debugging proxy.

Comment: Ok, I already have some similar proxies for this so one more shouldn't be too hard to set up. Thanks for the thorough example! I want it to proxy to any arbitrary ip, which can probably be done with nginx request variables.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use javascript to start a websocket connection with a dishonest `Origin` header of `Origin: test.com`?

If we could forge the origin of requests in JavaScript, the same origin policy wouldn't be very good at keeping us safe.  It exists solely to protect us from this and other potential attack vectors.

As this looks like dev work, have you considered using a web debugging proxy such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (free) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) (paid)?  With those you could modify the initial handshake request or response for the WebSocket for your own machine or any test machines that are proxied through the debugger.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, it protects users from bad js even though it doesn't protect servers from bad clients. I think I'll go with nginx, but those easy to use proxies look like they might be useful for someone else. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is to override the WebSocket call with another websocket library, like https://github.com/websockets/ws. To use this node.js library in a browser, you just have to use http://browserify.org/.

Comment: Also rejectUnauthorized: false could help next 2 origin option when server has invalid certificate...

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* must forge a fake 'origin' header value from javascript - there is a way. Its not something you will find in your generally accepted principles handbook, but here it is:

Create a php file that invokes the socket, with a fake origin value. Now call the php file using ajax, from you javascript.

It may not be elegant, ethical or acceptable, but never accept anyone telling you that it cant be done.

'send.php' was called using ajax from javascript

send.php contents

```
require "websocket_client.php";
$client = new Client("IP_ADDR:PORT", $_GET[mobile] ."|".$_GET[login]);
$client->send('1112223333|sms');
$client->send(json_encode(array('login'=>$user,'msg'=>$msg)));
echo $client->receive();`enter code here`
```

websocket_client.php was a class file with basic websocket functions (including the custom origin values

```
 /**


 * Perform WebSocket handshake
   */
  protected function connect() {
    $url_parts = parse_url($this->socket_uri);
    $scheme    = $url_parts['scheme'];
    $host      = $url_parts['host'];
    $user      = isset($url_parts['user']) ? $url_parts['user'] : '';
    $pass      = isset($url_parts['pass']) ? $url_parts['pass'] : '';
    $port      = isset($url_parts['port']) ? $url_parts['port'] : ($scheme === 'wss' ? 443 : 80);
    $path      = isset($url_parts['path']) ? $url_parts['path'] : '/';
    $query     = isset($url_parts['query'])    ? $url_parts['query'] : '';
    $fragment  = isset($url_parts['fragment']) ? $url_parts['fragment'] : '';

$path_with_query = $path;
if (!empty($query))    $path_with_query .= '?' . $query;
if (!empty($fragment)) $path_with_query .= '#' . $fragment;

if (!in_array($scheme, array('ws', 'wss'))) {
  throw new BadUriException(
    "Url should have scheme ws or wss, not '$scheme' from URI '$this->socket_uri' ."
  );
}

$host_uri = ($scheme === 'wss' ? 'ssl' : 'tcp') . '://' . $host;

// Open the socket.  @ is there to supress warning that we will catch in check below instead.
$this->socket = @fsockopen($host_uri, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->options['timeout']);

if ($this->socket === false) {
  throw new ConnectionException(
    "Could not open socket to \"$host:$port\": $errstr ($errno)."
  );
}

// Set timeout on the stream as well.
stream_set_timeout($this->socket, $this->options['timeout']);

// Generate the WebSocket key.
$key = self::generateKey();

// Default headers (using lowercase for simpler array_merge below).
$headers = array(
  'host'                  => $host . ":" . $port,
  'user-agent'            => 'websocket-client-php',
  'connection'            => 'Upgrade',
  'upgrade'               => 'websocket',
  'origin'               =>  $MY_CUSTOM_SHADY_VALUE,
  'sec-websocket-key'     => $key,
  'sec-websocket-version' => '13',
);

// Handle basic authentication.
if ($user || $pass) {
  $headers['authorization'] = 'Basic ' . base64_encode($user . ':' . $pass) . "\r\n";
}

// Deprecated way of adding origin (use headers instead).
if (isset($this->options['origin'])) $headers['origin'] = $this->options['origin'];

// Add and override with headers from options.
if (isset($this->options['headers'])) {
  $headers = array_merge($headers, array_change_key_case($this->options['headers']));
}

$header =
  "GET " . $path_with_query . " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
  . implode(
    "\r\n", array_map(
      function($key, $value) { return "$key: $value"; }, array_keys($headers), $headers
    )
  )
  . "\r\n\r\n";

// Send headers.
$this->write($header);

// Get server response.
$response = '';
do {
  $buffer = stream_get_line($this->socket, 1024, "\r\n");
  $response .= $buffer . "\n";
  $metadata = stream_get_meta_data($this->socket);
} while (!feof($this->socket) && $metadata['unread_bytes'] > 0);

/// @todo Handle version switching

// Validate response.
if (!preg_match('#Sec-WebSocket-Accept:\s(.*)$#mUi', $response, $matches)) {
  $address = $scheme . '://' . $host . $path_with_query;
  throw new ConnectionException(
    "Connection to '{$address}' failed: Server sent invalid upgrade response:\n"
    . $response
  );
}

$keyAccept = trim($matches[1]);
$expectedResonse
  = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($key . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));

if ($keyAccept !== $expectedResonse) {
  throw new ConnectionException('Server sent bad upgrade response.');
}

$this->is_connected = true;
```

}