# Websocket not attaching into docker container

Tags: java, web-services, docker

I have a Docker container containing OpenJDK8 and a webapp that provides services via websockets. I have a Java client that tests those ws services. They work fine outside docker.

But when I put my webapp inside a docker image and run the webapp the external testing java client cannot connect. Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: XNIO000812: Connection closed unexpectedly
at org.nustaq.kontraktor.remoting.websockets.JSR356ClientConnector$WSClientEndpoint.<init>(JSR356ClientConnector.java:104)
at org.nustaq.kontraktor.remoting.websockets.JSR356ClientConnector.connect(JSR356ClientConnector.java:73)
at org.nustaq.kontraktor.remoting.base.ActorClient.connect(ActorClient.java:72)
at org.nustaq.kontraktor.remoting.websockets.WebSocketConnectable.lambda$connect$36(WebSocketConnectable.java:66)
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.4
RUN apk --update add openjdk8
CMD ["/usr/bin/java", "-version"]

# This copies to local fat jar inside the image
ADD target/quokka-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /quokka-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD storage/*.mmf /storage/
ADD cwift.properties /

# What to run when the container starts
VOLUME ["/web"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "../quokka-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]

# Ports used by the app
EXPOSE 8080
```

Here are the commands and outputs I use to verify the port exposure:

```
david@david-desktop:~/csrepo/cwift$ docker exec suspicious_roentgen ps -Af
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
1 root       1:10 java -jar ../quokka-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./cswift.properties
38 root       0:00 ps -Af
david@david-desktop:~/csrepo/cwift$ docker exec suspicious_roentgen netstat -nap|grep 8080
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8080   :::*                    LISTEN      1/java
david@david-desktop:~/csrepo/cwift$ sudo netstat -nap |grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      28506/docker-proxy
```

I run it with this:

```
docker run -v /home/david/csrepo/cwift/web:/web -p 8080:8080 --rm cswebapp ./cwift.properties
```

Ideas?

Comment: how do you start the container?

Comment: run cmd added to the question. it is reading the external properties file correctly from the command line, as it outputs a console message that tells me so.

Comment: what are the other exposed ports doing?

Comment: also worth a try: -p 8123:8080 to make sure you talking to your container and not some other process

Comment: I published on 8123 in the webapp and mapped that to 8082 with docker -p command. Then changed the Java test client to use 8082, checked it was exposed with netstat. Same exception

Comment: sorry I'm not more helpful.
Last thing I'd check is if the Origin header check throws you off. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144233/how-to-set-websocket-origin-header-from-javascript

Comment: Given the exception shows it made a connection which was then immediately dropped I am assuming that the port EXPOSE is working and the issues lies with the webapp being embedded in docker. I'll build a docker image with the Kontraktor simple http example and see if that has the same issue.

Comment: After reading this https://thehftguy.com/2016/11/01/docker-in-production-an-history-of-failure/ and recognising the difficulty in debugging Docker network connection problems I am abandoning the use of Docker for this particular project.