# Connecting to webscoket from nodeJS server giving 'Unexpected server response: 403'

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am trying to connect to a WebSocket address (for e.g. 'wss://mycompany.com') using nodeJS websocket client: https://github.com/websockets/ws. I am successfully able to test the connection in a browser using [MDN's WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) but getting the following connection error when using nodeJS WebSocket client:

```
error: Error: Unexpected server response: 403
  at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (oda-node-sdk\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:579:7)
  at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:310:20)
  at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:596:27)
  at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
  at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:469:22)
  at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
  at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:9)
  at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
  at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
```

Server side is enterprise code providing me with the WebSocket host URL ((for e.g. 'wss://mycompany.com')).
I tested the below client code successfully for wss://echo.websocket.org but getting the above error for wss://mycompany.com. I tried connecting through mycompany's proxy tunnel but it doesn't help either. Can anyone suggest possible reasons for this?

Client Side code:

```js
var WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');

ws.on('open', function open() {
    console.log('connected')
    ws.send('something');
});

ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

ws.on('error', (error)=> {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Hi, are you trying it online? is your website working on https? on localhost, it doesn't metter if you ws or wss but https requires a wss connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unexpected server response 403 error is due to the fact that the server recognizes the connection request but fails to authorize it and doesn't allow connection. The connection was being rejected by the server as no origin header was set. The docs of [NodeJS WebSocket](https://github.com/websockets/ws) describe it as:

> If `verifyClient` is not set then the handshake is automatically accepted. If it is provided with a single argument then that is:
>
> info {Object}
>
> - origin {String} The value in the Origin header indicated by the client.
> - req {http.IncomingMessage} The client HTTP GET request.
> - secure {Boolean} true if req.connection.authorized or req.connection.encrypted is set.

For the part of setting origin properly, you can look at [How to set WebSocket Origin Header from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30144233/8421931)